# How to select elements in a Tensor based on some input data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

The problem I'm trying to solve is the one in the picture. Given a text sentence with word embeddings, and a fixed set of indexes for each sentence pointing to the words I want to keep, how do I slice the embeddings of interest?

[image: Problem description]
**Note**: I cannot do it as a preprocess step because the embeddings are the result of several layers.

As a toy example, say that I have 2 input datasets, one containing the data itself as 2D tensors, and another one containing the indices of the words that I'm interested in. So for instance

```
NUM_SENTENCES=2
NUM_ENTITIES_PER_REL=3
LEN_SENTENCE=5
NUM_H_T=2
DIM_EMBEDDING=2

indices = tf.constant([
   [1, 3],
   [0, 4]
])
data = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(NUM_SENTENCES*LEN_SENTENCE*DIM_EMBEDDING), [NUM_SENTENCES, LEN_SENTENCE, DIM_EMBEDDING]))
```

With the index as stated, I want to retrieve elements 1 and 3 from first element, and 0 and 4 from second to result in

```
array([[[ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[10, 11],
        [18, 19]]])
```

I can obtain desired result if I do:

```
selector = [[[idx, elem]
              for elem in arr]
              for idx, arr in enumerate(indices)]
tf.gather_nd(data, selector)
```

but this doesn't work within a model. Here it is my code:

```
input_text = keras.Input(shape=(LEN_SENTENCE, DIM_EMBEDDING), name="input_sentence")
input_ent = keras.Input(shape=(NUM_ENTITIES_PER_REL, 2), dtype=tf.int32, name="entities_to_classify")

class Selector(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Selector, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        h_s = inputs[1]
        indexes = inputs[0]
        idxs = indexes.numpy()
        selector = [[[idx, elem]
                      for elem in arr]
                      for idx, arr in enumerate(idxs)]

        return tf.gather_nd(h_s, selector)

x = Selector(name="selector")([input_ent, input_text])

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_ent, input_text], outputs=x, name='language_model')

keras.utils.plot_model(model, '/tmp/model.jpg', show_shapes=True)
```

and the result of executing it (I'm using `tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1`).

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

and I don't know how to solve this chicken-egg problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

NUM_SENTENCES = 2
NUM_ENTITIES_PER_REL = 3
LEN_SENTENCE = 5
NUM_H_T = 2
DIM_EMBEDDING = 2

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    indices = tf.constant([
       [1, 3],
       [0, 4]
    ])
    data = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(NUM_SENTENCES * LEN_SENTENCE * DIM_EMBEDDING),
                                  [NUM_SENTENCES, LEN_SENTENCE, DIM_EMBEDDING]))
    # Make first dimension indices
    s = tf.shape(indices)
    idx0 = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(s[0]), 1), [1, s[1]])
    # Make full index
    idx_gather = tf.stack([idx0, indices], axis=-1)
    # Gather result
    result = tf.gather_nd(data, idx_gather)
    print(sess.run(result))
    # [[[ 2  3]
    #   [ 6  7]]
    #
    #  [[10 11]
    #   [18 19]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensor can't be cast to numpy use data instead

```py
idxs = indexes[0].numpy()
```

Comment: I'm still getting same exception `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: You don't really need numpy to provide indexes
```selector = [[[idx, elem] for elem in arr] for idx, arr in zip(range(indexes),indexes)]```

Comment: Your suggestion is equivalent to the enumerate I have. I tried before without the `.numpy()` but then I get a different kind of error
`TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass dynamic=True to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
        "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "

    TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
`